# Dynamically disable children button components inside an ngfor

Tags: angular

I have a component to manage groups of buttons dynamically. The main purpose is to get a component for buttons controlling theyr click events and enable/disable status, not only when they are rendered, I need to change the `disabled` attribute in many cases. That will be different every time I include the component on any page depending of the page requeriments (parent component requeriments). The idea is to serve the data with a JSON inside an `@input`. I have the click event working, but I need to know how to manage the enable/disable actions. Initially I don't know how many buttons could be in each case.

Here is the template of the child component:

```
<div class="dynamic-button-group-container">
  <div *ngFor="let btnDefinition of buttonGroupDefinitions">
    <button
      [disabled]="btnDefinition.disabled"
      (click)="btnDefinition.action()"
    >
      {{ btnDefinition.text }}
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

the problem here is that `[disabled]="btnDefinition.disabled"` is only rendered and never change again

Here the relevant script of the child component:

```
@Input() buttonGroupDefinitions!: ButtonGroupDefinitions [];
```

here is the parent component from I wanted to manage dynamically the actions (remember that the idea is to use the child component in many places on the application with different requirements:

```
<app-dynamic-button-group [buttonGroupDefinitions]="buttonGroupDefinitions">
```

and here is an example of the json:

```
this.buttonGroupDefinitions = [
      {
        text: "name1",
        action: this.something1,
        disabled: true
      },
      {
        text: "name2",
        action: this.something2,
        disabled: false
      },
      {
        text: "name3",
        action: this.something3,
        disabled: false
      }
    ]
```

Here in the parent component I'm gonna take the actions from the events like that:

```
something3() {
    //This could do anything and works fine
    //Maybe this can disable the name2 button and enable the name1
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more? This all depends on your conditions.
For example : 1 button to disable them all -> variable to save the button that was focused.
I dont think it matter much how many buttons there are but more on what conditions you are thinking on.

Comment: sure, I have just added more info and examples

Comment: Is there a reason your passing down json instead objects? You could use the json to generate you objects and pass these objects down to your children. 

Again your conditions is what determines the difficulty. Do you have for example buttons green, red, ... you could save the green,red button objects in an array respectifully.

Comment: in fact I can use json or objects or whatever, but is not for prefefined buttons on database is for agyle adding for button groups on an application that has a lot of them yn many sections. Yes could be more attributes like colour and similars (I will made this with css classes). Simply I need to pass from the father to the child a dynamic boolean for disabled attribute, but It doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isnt a full awnser with code, im a bit busy right now.

What you could do is adapt your JSON file for these changes.
Instead of going just the definition of your buttons, you could add the group of buttons together like the red button, green button.

```
{"buttons": {
"green": {
    "text": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
    "action": "main_window",
    "disabled": false
},
"red": { 
    "text": "Images/Sun.png",
    "action": "this.something()",
    "disabled": false
}
```

}}

The parent will make these into objects

```
class Model {
   text: string;
   action : your action;
   disabled : boolean;
}
```

Now you could write a function that would loop over the buttons, save the green and red as key values and when a red button is clicked you will be able to tell this and do your conditions based on this.

You wanne pass down variables instead of the json you got from  github or your api. You wanne dynamically change these values. Like with enable or disabling your buttons.

Comment: Oh now I see, you're right, Thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can not get click event by disabling button.
You can handle this from your function.

For Example:

```
<div class="dynamic-button-group-container">
  <div *ngFor="let btnDefinition of buttonGroupDefinitions;let i=index">
    <button
      (click)="onButtonClick(i)"
    >
      {{ btnDefinition.text }}
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
@Output() selectedValueEmit = new EventEmitter();
public onButtonClick(index: any): void {
  this.selectedValueEmit.emit(index);
}
```

```html
<app-dynamic-button-group
  [buttonGroupDefinitions]="buttonGroupDefinitions"
  (selectedValueEmit)="onButtonClick($event)" />
```

```js
onButtonClick(index: number): void {
  switch (index) {
    case '0':
      this.something1();
      break;
    case '1':
      this.something2();
      break; `enter code here`
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks but in that case I could only change the clicked button and I need to be able to change the others. Is for that I discarted the @output

Comment: You can change others button also by modifying your buttonGroupDefinitions array.